# "Could not find a part of the path" looking for a UNC path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Trying to access a network share on another computer from the IIS server.
Code works fine on my development machine

`return File(path, "application/msexcel",trimmedPath);`

But when I try on the server I get this

`Could not find a part of the path 'r:\results\19262\19262-BA-T1\19262-BA-T1-19262-BA-T1-2_12_11_2014_32C_CST_8870.xlsx'.`

If I copy that path into explorer it opens on the server.
I'm using Windows integrated security
In IIS I have set Physical path credentials to my userID

Tried Proc Monitor

[image: ProcMon]

Comment: Does the user that is running the IIS app pool process have rights to that folder?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because in IIS the process in running under the application pool user credentials. By default that user has very limited permissions. What you can do is try switching it to the NETWORK SERVICE user.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to above, I think you'd need to access the path via UNC, and not a mapped drive. Drives are mapped using the credentials of the logged in user (or credentials provided in the NET USE statement), and IIS is likely not using those credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You have to impersonate your site with the username and password, which having full/proper rights to the network resources you are accessing.

Just impersonate you site writing below code in System.Web section of web.config file.,

```
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<identity impersonate="true" userName="Charan" password="Ghate"/>
```

Here I am assuming that user name "Charan" is having full access rights to the network resources you are accessing. and "Ghate" is the password of the user. I solved by this; when I was trying to access shared resources (Files) on network. so I think that this should surly works.